# Error when trying to create a bin column via cut

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am getting an error for trying to create a column with binned values as below:

```
bins = [1, 10, 20, 21, 34]
labels = [1-10, 11-20, 21-34, 35]
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['Number of Clinics'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

I am getting error: `ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique`

Not sure what I am missing? The number of clinics column just contains a value between 1 and 100 that I want to bin between 1-10, 11-20, 21-34 and 35+, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `labels` to `str` and correct your `bin`

```
bins = [1, 10, 20, 34, 100]
labels = ['1-10', '11-20', '21-34', '35+']
```

Comment: Thanks!, is there a number I can use instead of 100, to show  34 +? or 34 - infinite?

Comment: @Chris90 labels = ['1-10', '11-20', '21-34', '34 - Inf'] ?

Comment: @Chris90 bins = [1, 10, 20, 34, np.Inf]